# Count how many non-zero entries at each month in a dataframe column

Tags: pandas, count

I have a dataframe, `df`, with `datetimeindex` and a single column, like this:

[image]
[image]

I need to count how many non-zero entries i have at each month. For example, according to those images, in January i would have 2 entries, in February 1 entry and in March 2 entries. I have more months in the dataframe, but i guess that explains the problem.

I tried using pandas `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).count()
```

But that just gives me total days at each month and i don't saw any other parameter in `count()` that i could use here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [index.to_period()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html)

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x_df = pd.DataFrame( 
     {
          'values': np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(120,)) 
     } ,
           index = pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=120, freq="D")
)
In [2]: x_df

Out[2]: 
            values
2022-01-01       0
2022-01-02       0
2022-01-03       1
2022-01-04       0
2022-01-05       0
           ...
2022-04-26       1
2022-04-27       0
2022-04-28       0
2022-04-29       1
2022-04-30       1

[120 rows x 1 columns]

In [3]: x_df[x_df['values'] != 0].groupby(lambda x: x.to_period("M")).count()

Out[3]: 
         values
2022-01      17
2022-02      15
2022-03      16
2022-04      17
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
#drop nans
import numpy as np
dfx['col1']=dfx['col1'].replace(0,np.nan)
dfx=dfx.dropna()

dfx=dfx.resample('1M').count()
```